# Have regex find blank carriage returns

Tags: php, html, mysql, regex

I have a TEXTAREA on my form that saves to MySQL. Works 100%. Users can use most HTML expressions in it such as font size and color. When displaying the TEXTAREA variable in HTML I use REGEX to sift out all the tags like  and it works 100% as well. The problem that I'm having is that when a user wants to do a line break (or carriage return or new paragraph, etc), MYSQL shows it as such:

```
$str="stuff
more stuff";//this is how I see it in MYSQL
```

but when displayed it is:

```
echo $str;//output is "stuff more stuff"
```

Any suggestions? I was thinking of listening for the user to hit ENTER and then adding 
 before saving to the MYSQL but I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: You do not need to use two line breaks to make a new paragraph if your text is in a code block. However, if your text is not in a code block, you will need two line breaks to create a new paragraph.

Comment: It looks like you want to use [`nl2br(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) or an equivalent of that in an other programming language.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I looked into nl2br(...) but problem is that there is no <BR/> or \n being saved to my database so when I look at the data in MySQL its WYSIWYG just a line break with no tags to convert

Comment: I think with regex probably you are removing the ENTER, check this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php to allow tags you only need without regex.

Comment: @StevenVanerp That doesn't make sense to me. Why would the database show it as a linebreak if there is no `\n` or `\r`. A newline in html is treated as any whitespace, but a `<br/>` tag will show a newline. If the user hits enter inside a textarea, the browser will send a newline to the server on that place if the form is submitted. Are you filtering out the newlines somewhere?

Comment: All I have is a simple textarea option in a form that is saved "as-is" to MYSQL. There is no script to add or remove any tags. When I view the database via PHPMYADMIN, the data is saved with apparently invisible linebreaks but it does do it. I'm running the latest version of WAMP if that helps

Comment: I stand corrected. It only looked like the linebreaks were invisible but upon displaying the data it comes out as one line. So I guess I'm back to needing a way to "listen" for the user to hit ENTER and insert a <BR> tag.